# Android activity over lock screen specifically

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

Trying to show my Overlay activity over device lock screen - Its Working fine. The problem when my phone ringing | Alarm ringing  that time I can see the overlay only. Cancel my overlay then only i can see.. how to avoid that

My code for display activity

```
 Window window = getWindow();
      window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
           | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
           | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
           | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```